# ¿ Como mostrar un modal condicionado para verlo solo cuando se cumpla x condicion ? ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

En primera instancia tengo productos que los traigo desde una Api y los muestro en un componente luego de hacerle un .map(), no todos los productos tienen asociado un producto_adicional es por ello que quiero hacer una condicion que cuando el producto tenga productos_adicionales delo contrario no lo muestre.

...

```
       <Modal
          isOpen={showModal}
          onRequestClose={() => setShowModal(false)}
          className="Modal"
          >
          <button className="close-modal" onClick={() => setShowModal(false)}>
            x
          </button>
          <div className="additional-details">
            <div className="additional-name">
              <Zoom>
                {additionals.map((additional) => {
                  return (
                    <ModalAdditional
                      additional={additional}
                      key={additional.additional.product_id}
                      item={item}
                      onClick={onClick}
                    />
                  );
                })}
              </Zoom>
            </div>
          </div>
      </Modal>
```

...

Comment: Por favor comparte con la comunidad,  cómo se ve la estructura del array `additionals`; así como lo muestras, parece tener un objeto asignado como atributo en la propiedad `additional`, saludos

Comment: Buenas amigo gracias, mira lo que pasa es que uso REDUX entonces yo additionals lo traigo desde un dispatch y lo mando a llamar luego con useEffect para usarlo con un hooks de redux que se llama Use selector y de ahi es que llevo toda esa informacion de la api

Answer (score 0):

puedes intentar esto:

```
          <Modal
              isOpen={showModal}
              onRequestClose={() => setShowModal(false)}
              className="Modal"
              >
              <button className="close-modal" onClick={() => setShowModal(false)}>
                x
              </button>
              <div className="additional-details">
                <div className="additional-name">
                  <Zoom>
                    {additionals.map((additional) => {
                      if(additional){
                        return (
                          <ModalAdditional
                            additional={additional}
                            key={additional.additional.product_id}
                            item={item}
                            onClick={onClick}
                          />
                        );
                       }

                    })}
                  </Zoom>
                </div>
              </div>
          </Modal>
```

Comment: Puede intentar o eso funciona?

Comment: En esta solución solo se pregunta si existe el elemento del array `additionals`, no toma en cuenta las demás propiedades. hay que darle un double check.

Comment: Claro yo lo había pensado solo que resulta, que cada producto tiene un id verdad, entonces los additionals contienen un array de objetos y unos parámetros propios entonces, cuando yo le doy click el me trae todo los adiciones solo quiero traer el adicional que hace parte ese ID se que esta un poco dificil de explicar jaja

Answer (score 0):

```
    {additionals.lenght ? (
       {additionals?.map((additional) => {
                    return (
                      <ModalAdditional
                        additional={additional}
                        key={additional.additional.product_id}
                        item={item}
                        onClick={onClick}
                      />
                    );
                })}
```

):(No se encuentran datos)}

Comment: Hola, por favor lee [answer]

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica cómo este código responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.